# How to map through an array of objects and add the total in each object to a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, array.prototype.map

Here is an array of objects

```
const items = [{description: "Cement", total: "150"}, {description: "Mortar", total: "200"}, {description: "Sand", total: "100"}]
```

**I want to add the total of each object to a variable so that i can get the grand total of everything.**

I have tried mapping through the items array and then for each item.total i added it to a variable but it does not work.

```
items.map((item) => {
          let sum = 0
          sum += item.total
})
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not working, because you initialize a new variable inside a loop in each iteration. In your example the `sum` variable should be in a global scope. Moreover you should convert strings to numbers to sum them. Here is fixed version of your code:

```js
const items = [{description: "Cement", total: "150"}, {description: "Mortar", total: "200"}, {description: "Sand", total: "100"}];

let sum = 0;

items.map((item) => {
  sum += Number(item.total);
});

console.log(sum);
```

However in such cases when you want to accumulate array values to a single value, it's better to use `reduce` method:

```js
const items = [{description: "Cement", total: "150"}, {description: "Mortar", total: "200"}, {description: "Sand", total: "100"}];

const sum= items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + Number(item.total), 0);


console.log(sum);
```

Comment: `map` is definitely the wrong approach. If you're going to iterate with an array method like that `forEach` is much more suitable.

Comment: My answer had only `reduce` variant at first. I added `map`, only because  OP used it. I wanted to explain why the code from example is not working. Even if `map` is used against its original purpose here, it does the job, so i keep it as it is ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`map` is the wrong method to use as it's a *transformative* method which returns a new array of changed elements. `reduce` (as the other answers suggest) might be useful here but - rather than overcomplicate things - you could just use [a simple loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement).

Make sure to coerce the `total` value (a string) of each object to an integer.

```js
const items = [{description: "Cement", total: "150"}, {description: "Mortar", total: "200"}, {description: "Sand", total: "100"}];

let sum = 0;

for (const item of items) {
  sum += Number(item.total);
}

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: I understand. I need to brush up my knowledge of high order functions in Javascript :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use reduce method:

```
items.reduce((result, item) => result + parseInt(item.total), 0);
```

Comment: You should always include the radix for `parseInt` as it won't always be guaranteed to default to `10`,